# How can I wait for home directory to appear when using Puppet?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I have puppet script below to create a user and an authorized SSH key which fails 50% of the time. It seems that /home/$username is created in the background and is not always there when the creation of .ssh and authorized keys is attempted. Puppet fail because /home/$username does not exist. But when I look a second later it has actually been created.

How can make puppet not continue until the home directory is actually fully created?

```
  user { $username:
    name => $username,
    managehome => true,
    shell => "/bin/bash",
    groups => [ 'dip', 'admin' ];
  }

  file { "/home/${username}/.ssh":
    ensure => 'directory';
  }

  file { "/home/${username}/.ssh/authorized_keys":
    owner => "${username}",
    group => "${username}",
    mode => '0664',
    content => "${ssh_public_key}"
  }
```

Puppet 3.3.1 and Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for, is the meta parameter (meaning you can specify it for any class) `require`.

I assume that your puppet script is wrapped in a scope with access to `$username`, thus something like this would work:

```
user { $username:
    name => $username,
    managehome => true,
    shell => "/bin/bash",
    groups => [ 'dip', 'admin' ]
}

file { "/home/${username}/.ssh":
    ensure => 'directory',
    require => User["$username"]
}

file { "/home/${username}/.ssh/authorized_keys":
    require => File["/home/${username}/.ssh"],
    owner => "${username}",
    group => "${username}",
    mode => '0664',
    content => "${ssh_public_key}"
}
```